# WordPress Multi Site not cropping images on upload

Tags: wordpress, image

I just installed Multsite and started playing with it. I notices that when I upload an image, it's not creating the thumbnail or medium size images. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Bear in mind if the source image you're uploading is *smaller* than the size presets, WP will not generate the different sizes. In other words, it won't create images *larger* than what you provide.

Comment: I'm uploading larger images and looking for the 150x150 cropped image and it's not creating it.

Comment: Check that `functions.php` contains `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )`. If it does, can you confirm which plugins and theme you're using.

Comment: I was using my own theme and it has add_theme_support. I have switched to 2017 theme and disabled all plugins and it still is not creating the thumbs. I feel like I might be missing a setting but under settings I have crop set to 1.

Comment: You might need to check permissions on your uploads folder so that WP can write to them. Failing that, the only other thing I can think of is that your server doesn't have GD support for PHP.

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.zoopable.com/check-php-gd-library-installed-or-not/) to check that GD is installed.

Comment: You're awesome! It was GD thanks so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome; I've added it as answer to help others. Feel free to accept it so the question can be closed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following:

1. `functions.php` should contain `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`
2. Check the permissions for your uploads folder to ensure that WordPress can write to them
3. Check that the GD library is enabled for PHP by using `phpinfo()`